# How to prove sample correlation coefficient of Y and estimate of Y is equal to 1?

Tags: regression, correlation

Hi I'm trying to proveample correlation coefficient of Y and estimate of Y is equal to 1 in simple regression analysis($Y=\beta_o+\beta_1X+\epsilon$), that is
$r_{y\hat y}=1$.

I used $R^2=r_{y\hat y}^2$ and $\sum y=\sum \hat y$. So

$R^2=SSR/SST=(\sum \hat y^2-n\bar y^2)/(\sum y^2-n\bar y^2)=1$ and I'm trying to prove $\sum \hat y^2=\sum  y^2$ but I couldn't go further than this.
How could I prove this?

And also is $\sum e_iy_i=0 $ also correct statement in simple regression analysis?

Thank you for everyone.

-edit

A solution of my textbook for this problem is as follow;

$r_{y\hat y}=S_{y\hat y}/S_yS_\hat y$. Enough to show $\sum (y_i-\bar y)(\hat y_i -\bar y)=(\sum (y_i-\bar y)^2)^{1/2}(\sum (\hat y_i-\bar y)^2)^{1/2}$

$\hat y$ is linear in y. By Coach-Schwarz inequality, $E[(y_i-\bar y)(\hat y_i -\bar y)]=E[(y_i-\bar y)^2]^{1/2}$ (I couldn't understand how this equality is satisfied.) and $\bar x$ is a consistent of $E[X]$.

$(\sum (y_i-\bar y)(\hat y_i -\bar y))^2=(\sum (y_i-\bar y)^2)(\sum (\hat y_i-\bar y)^2)$.

Comment: Why would it be 1?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica A problem in my textbook is to prove it.

Comment: 1. See the [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on homework-style problems. 2. I expect there's some context missing from the question.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your advice. And unfortunately, this is all it said in my textbook(and maybe there  is a mistake in translating because I'm not natural speaker.)

Comment: take (say) three non-collinear points. Like x = 1,2,3  y=2,4,5 and calculate the thing you're trying to prove is 1.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica If my calculation is right, it's not equal to 1. Thanks, I think a problem has mistakes or some missed assumption.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica And I accidentally found  correlation coefficient of X and estimate of Y is equal to 1 for 2 examples. Are these just coincidence?

Comment: In your examples, the points are collinear. It's *possible* for the correlation to be 1, but you have a counterexample where it isn't 1, and  a way to make more (make them non-collinear). In your examples, try scrambling up the y's a little (swap two which have different x's, for example) but leaving the x's where they were and seeing what happens to the correlation.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!